# How to send to a jsp page from a rest call

Tags: java, jsp, rest, jersey, web

I've written a rest interface (with jersey), a browser will be calling this rest interface. I would like show some html/jsp to the user as a response to this rest call...

Is this possible? How do I do it?

Comment: Will this REST interface be called from a browser or programmatically through something like CUrl or wget? Would you like the JSP code to be displayed, or just return the processed output like normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. [This post](http://blog.docuverse.com/2009/08/04/using-jsp-with-jersey-jax-rs-implementation/) as well as [this one](http://blogs.oracle.com/sandoz/entry/mvcj) gives a hint how to use `Viewable`s to return JSPs as a response.